# Form Data Causes "Page Not Found"

Tags: search, query

If you go to http://redoakchrysler.net/vehicles/new-vehicle-inventory and select 2012 from the drop down menu in the years list, you will be taken to a 'page not found' page.  But if you select any other year, or any other option in the drop down menus, it performs the search correctly.

Has anyone ever experienced this before, or know why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need to see your code that processes this form data.

Comment: @Sean Carruthers year is an internal query_var. Try renaming your year field to something else. e.g: make_year

Comment: @HameedullahKhan Thanks, that worked perfectly! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change $year to another variable.